# What are the first 3 ordinal numbers in the set of all integers?

Tags: ordinals

I've been reading a little bit about Cantor's work with transfinite numbers, and one point is confusing me.

If my understanding is correct, the set of positive integers ω and the set of negative integers ω* have the same cardinality (Aleph-0), but different order types. But it's simple for me to pull describe the first 3 ordinals in those sets because they have a single vector (incrementation or decrementation): [1,2,3,...] and [-1,-2,-3,...] This leads to confusion about how I describe the first 3 ordinals in the set of all integers because ℤ = [...,-3,-2,-1, 0, 1, 2, 3,...]

- What are the first three ordinal numbers in the set of all integers ℤ?

Comment: $0$, $1$, $2{}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But where do you start from with 0?  Unlike ω and ω*, there is not defined beginning or ending.

Comment: It is unclear what is meant by "first $n$ ordinal numbers in $X$." That question indicates a confusion about what is meant by "ordinal number."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm really asking about how you can determine a starting point for natural ordinals in a set that doesn't have a beginning or ending, unlike ω or ω*

Comment: @DukeZhou I looked at your set, wrote down the smallest ordinal in that set (easy, since $0$ is the smallest ordinal of all), then wrote down the next one, and the one after that.

Comment: You can't - you need a well-ordered set, not just an ordered or linear-ordered set. But there are no ordinal numbers in $\{-1,-2,\dots\}$ either, in the definition of "ordinal numbers." The ordinal numbers are $0,1,2,\dots$.

Comment: Why should there be such a thing as a *natural* "first three ordinals" in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If the first three ordinals of $\mathbb N$ are 1,2 and 3, what are the *last* three ordinals?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine because ordinal numbers are a generalization of the natural numbers

Comment: And why would that tell us the notion naturally helps us with $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I don't think it helps with ℤ at all.  I'm trying to understand why ordinal numbers are restricted to a generalization of the natural numbers, and cannot also be a generalization of integers.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Because the ordinals are well-ordered.

Comment: The Integers with the standard greater than order is not a well ordered set.  It can be well ordered if you use a different order but it is not well ordered with *that* order.  What the first three elements would be would depend and what well-ordering you put in them.  i.e. it's possible that they could be *any* three.  One order could be $a << b$ if either $|a|<|b|$ or if $|a| = |b|$ then $a = -b < 0$.  Then the first seven elements are $0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown - And?

Comment: Asking why the ordinals don't generalize the integers is an absurd question. Because they weren't defined in a way that would do so. They were defined in a way such that any non-empty set of ordinal numbers has a least member, and integers do not have this property.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Your attitude regarding the absurdity of the question is quite common ;)

Comment: I hope it's clear that I don't mean to be derogatory by the use of that word; I don't mean it in the sense of "it's a question no reasonable person should formulate" but more like "it's a question whose internal workings turn out not to come together."

Comment: @MaliceVidrine No offense taken.  I fully understand why ordinals have to be whole numbers, but am trying to understand why they can only be natural numbers.  I've been trying to get at the root of this for a while now, with no result *(my Stack questions are not well received in general;)* so I finally asked a purposefully absurd question and did garner an answer that clarified the issue in a useful way.  More absurdity: "The *first* ordinal in the set of all integers is 0" but after that it gets more convoluted, and doesn't seem answerable within the existing framework.

Comment: It's perfectly answerable, and has been answered. We defined wellorders to do certain things, and an ordering that extends $\mathbb Z$ don't do that thing. Looking at your comment on Thomas Andrews' answer, you seem to have observed that there's an induction principle in the integers "from the middle" that doesn't appear to fit into ordinary transfinite induction; but in fact you can reduce the former to the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm really asking about how you can determine a starting point for natural ordinals in a set that doesn't have a beginning or ending.

I think you misunderstand what "ordinals" are. Ordinals do not generalize the *integers*; they generalize the *natural numbers*. Ordinals describe orderings with a certain important property: **well-orderedness**. A linear order is well-ordered if every (nonempty) subset of it has a least element. This is true of the natural numbers (think about proof by induction), but not of the integers (e.g. there is no least integer).

EDIT:

You write further

> I'm trying to understand why ordinal numbers are restricted to a generalization of the natural numbers, and cannot also be a generalization of integers.

Well, there's no reason we couldn't have generalized the integers instead, but we chose to generalize the naturals. It comes down to *what we want ordinals to do*; and the motivation for ordinals is *transfinite induction*. Just like we have induction on the natural numbers, we can use induction on any well-ordering: if $(L,<)$ is a well-ordering, and $X\subseteq L$ is such that

- $X$ is nonempty, and
- If $x\in L$ and every $y<x$ is in $X$, then $x\in X$,

then $X=L$. (Why? Suppose otherwise, and think about the set $L\setminus X$ ...)

This is an incredibly useful technique in mathematics (as is one of its applications, *definition by transfinite recursion*). Ordinals are introduced as a way of codifying this technique.

Comment: Thank you!  This clarifies the issue enormously!

Comment: @DukeZhou Glad to help!

Comment: @DukeZhou What does "the first number before $0$" mean? Are you referring to $-1$?

Comment: yes, -1.  (Naively, I can't shake the idea of "bipolar ordinality" because I see real world applications.  Even if we say -N is merely signed N, it seems to me the opposite vectors -/+ are meaningful. I also see the bipolar use of coordinates in Hamkins' [infinite Sudoku](http://jdh.hamkins.org/infinite-sudoku-and-the-sudoku-game/) to "order" the cells in regions/blocks on an infinite sudoku.  I'm guessing me calling those ordinals breaks some things, and is why my way of thinking about it is met with so much hostility:)  Anyway, I do appreciate your nearly inexhausible patience with me!

Comment: *(I'm trying to reform my reputation so I can ask questions on this forum again, but I may be hopeless case;)*

Answer (score 3):

You are misusing the word "ordinal number," which might indicate a confusion.

The ordinal numbers are $0,1,2,\dots.$ Historically, before some of modern set theory, ordinal numbers started at $1$, and could be thought of as a "place in a race" - first place, second place, etc.  Starting at $0$ is nice for set theorists, and you can think of the sentence "Person $X$ is in the $n$th ordinal position" as meaning that there are exactly $n$ people who beat $X$ in the race. (But it gets more complicated when dealing with infinite ordinals.)

In general, a well-ordered set $X$ is a set with an order $\leq$ which has the property that if $S\subseteq X$ is non-empty, then $S$ has a least element.

If this were a race, the condition of well-ordered would mean that you can find one winner in any slice of the racers - you could take the racers who are left-handed botanists, and, if there were any left-handed botanists in the race, you could determine who won amongst the left-handed botanists.

Given a well-ordered set, you can say "Which element of $X$ is at position $n$?" where $n$ is an ordinal number. Sometimes, when $n$ is too large, the answer is none. For example, in a race of $4$ people, if we ask who came in fifth place (ordinal place $4$), you'd say "nobody."

So, your $\omega^*$ is well-ordered, as is $\omega$. So you can say "what are the first $3$ places in these orders", or you can think of it as "What races beat the racer in third place?"

But $\mathbb Z$ is not a well-ordered set. In particular, it doesn't have a least element. But $\mathbb Q^{\geq 0}$ is also not a well-ordered, even though $0$ is the least element of $\mathbb Q$, because there are subsets of $\mathbb Q^{\geq 0}$ which do not have a least element. We can't find a winner for all subsets of the "racers" in this race.

Comment: This makes sense.  Ordinals as a generalization of the natural numbers is limited to well ordered sets.

Comment: I guess some of my confusion arises from techniques like [astronomical year numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering), which seems to employ negative dates in an ordinal manner, and which numbers are subsequently used in functions.  My guess is that this model requires "negative ordinality" because the exact age of the universe is not known, and ordering from a starting point is not possible.

Comment: Where does that link reference ordinals? Ordinals, as a mathematical concept, are very specific, while various other concepts in other fields might occasionally be called ordinal, but in a less rigorous mathematical sense.

Comment: That clarifies things.  Dates are numbers that have an "ordinal" function in the sense that they are a method of ordering time, but are not ordinals in a set theory context?  I guess I'm struggling with the question of why elements of a set cannot be ordered in relation to the center of the set for sets that don't have a beginning or an ending, or even for sets that do have a beginning and ending. *(Possibly this is just a function of naivete on my part, being new to set theory and number theory, and it would not be inaccurate to say one could fill volumes with what I do not know;)*

Comment: Dates are well-ordered (assuming there is some beginning to time) but they are not ordinal numbers. *However* you write dates, doesn't change which date is the first, second, third, etc.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to break this down.  Semantics definitely seem to be a big part of the issue, specifically the proper definition and usage of "ordinal".  (I've noticed a similar problem in relation to combinatorial games, where mathematician have precise definitions of what constitutes a game, mechanics, and conditions, as opposed to general public, where terms and concepts are less precise.) This leads me to a question on cardinality I'm sort of afraid to ask, but probably will anyway...

Answer (score 1):

An ordinal number is to describe the order of a number within a **well-ordered** set.  A well ordered set is a set of elements *and an order* so that certain properties are met[$*$].

The Natural numbers with the order "$>$" being the usual order we've known and loved since kindergarden is a well-ordering.

The negative integers with the order "$>$" is *not* a well-ordering.  However if we use the order "$<$", it is.  (And in turn the Natural numbers with the order "$<$" is *not* well ordered.)

The integers are not well-ordered with either "$<$" or with "$>$".  However "$<$" and "$>$" are not even *remotely* close to the only orders.

Let $>_*$ be defined as $a >_* 5$ for all $a \in Z$.  Otherwise if $a< 0 < b$ then $b >1> a$.  And if neither of those apply, then $b >_* a \iff |b| > |a|$.  That is well ordered and the first three ordinals are $5, -1, -2$.

But that's a silly and arbitrary ordering.

If two sets $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality, then there exists a bijection, $f:X \rightarrow Y$.  If $X$ has a well-ordering $>_X$ then defining an order $>_Y$ on $Y$ as $a>_Y b \iff f^{-1}(a) >_X f^{-1}(b)$ will be a well-ordering.

So for example if $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb Z$ via $f(n) = \frac n2$ if $n$ is even, and $f(n) = \frac {n+1}2$ if $n$ is odd, then the order "$>_Z$" defined as $z >_Z y \iff f^{-1}(z) > f^{-1}(y)$ we be a well-ordering;  we will have $0 <_Z -1 <_Z 1 <_Z -2 <_Z 2 ....$; and the "first three" integers will be $0,-1,1$.

And just for giggles.  Remember $>_*$ above?  The weird one?  We can use that to define $>_N$ on $\mathbb N$ where $a >_N b \iff f(a) >_* f(b)$.  That would order the Natural numbers as $\{10, 1,3,5,7....\}$.

====

[$*$]  1)  exactly one of $a >> b; a=b; b>0$ must be true.  2) $a >>b; b>>c \implies a>>c$.  And 3) all subsets have an element $a$ where $x >> a$ for all $a \ne a$.

The last is true for $>$ but not for $<$ on the Naturals.  The last is true for $<$ but not $>$ on the negative Naturals.  The last is *not* true for either $<$ or $>$ on the integers.

Comment: This is interesting. I would usually take $\leq$ to be the "usual" ordering on the naturals.

Comment: Yeah, me too.  And it is a "natural" ordering.  But it's not the *only* ordering. ...  Or are you commenting about ">" rather than "<".  I was basically copying directly from the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number , which for reasons unknown to me define the relation ">" rather than the relation "<".  I'm not sure why they made that choice as I prefer to go left to right and least to greater.  Doesn't really matter.

Comment: I was commenting on the latter part. I know there are plenty of choices for orderings.